# Android - Fragments Overlap

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, overlap

So I'm having an issue where when I click on my floating action button, the next fragment pops up but the other stays. What I want to happen is when I click the button, it disappears along with the fragment its on, then have the next fragment pop up.

Here is the fragment class with the button

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ScoutFragment extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton addDataScout;

    public ScoutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    } //End of ScoutFragment

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scout, container, false);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        //Setups Floating Action Button
        FloatingActionButton addDataScout = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        addDataScout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddScoutDataFragment fragment = new AddScoutDataFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layoutScout, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } //End of onClick
        }); //End of setOnClickListener
        return view;
    } //End of onCreateView
} //End of class
```

Here is the fragment class that I want to pop up

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AddScoutDataFragment extends Fragment {
    public AddScoutDataFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    } //End of AddScoutDataFragment

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_scout_data, container, false);
    } //End of onCreateView
} //End of class
```

Here is the xml file of the button fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutScout"
    tools:context="com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.ramfernoscout.ScoutFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="61dp"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_add"
            app:backgroundTint="#F28016"
            app:elevation="5dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:clickable="true">
        </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Western University"
            android:id="@+id/testText"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the xml file for the fragment I want to pop up

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_add_scout_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.ramfernoscout.AddScoutDataFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Accept Me"
        android:id="@+id/testViewData"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Starting my fragments through MainAcitivty which extends AppCompatActivity and implements NavigationView

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_welcome) {
        //Set the fragment initially
        WelcomeFragment fragment = new WelcomeFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        // Handle the camera action
    } 
    else if (id == R.id.nav_facebook) {
        FacebookFragment fragment = new FacebookFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } 
    else if (id == R.id.nav_members) {
        //Set the fragment initially
        MembersFragment fragment = new MembersFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } 
    else if (id == R.id.nav_robot) {

    } 
    else if (id == R.id.nav_scout) {
        //Set the fragment initially
        ScoutFragment fragment = new ScoutFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } 
    else if (id == R.id.nav_match) {
        //Set the fragment initially
        MatchFragment fragment = new MatchFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } //End of if statement

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
} //End of onNavigationItemSelected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you pass the id of a view within the current fragment to the replace method. That node in the view hierarchy currently does not contain a fragment, so it will just be added. You will have to pass the id of the view which contains the ScoutFragment. (If you inflated the fragment using xml the id should be the one on the `<fragment>` tag. If you inflated it from code pass the same id as you passed in your activity)

Comment: I just set that in the java class. It works, but the first fragment didn't exit, it stayed there then was covered by the second fragment. Is there anyway I can see it exit while the next fragment enters?

Comment: Ah I see, I think it is then because you pass the id of a view within the current fragment to the replace method. That node in the view hierarchy currently does not contain a fragment, so it will just be added. You will have to pass the id of the view which contains the ScoutFragment. (If you inflated the fragment using xml the id should be the one on the `<fragment>` tag. If you inflated it from code pass the same id as you passed in your activity)

Comment: I'm still sort of confused on what to do here, can you give me a coded example?

Comment: How do you start the ScoutFragment?

Comment: In that case you need to pass `R.id.fragment_container` instead of `R.id.layoutScout` to the replace method in the ScoutFragment. Note that `getFragmentManager()` method in a support Fragment returns the FragmentManager which manages that fragment, so it is the SupportFragmentManager from your activity